# Using dask.DataFrame.to_parquet() to write large file

Tags: python, pandas, dask, parquet

I have a .pq file (about 2Gb) in which I want to change a column name using dask.

I have no problems reading the file to dask DataFrame and also I'm able to rename columns.
But when it comes to writing the .pq file back to disk with ddf.to_parquet(), the job fails as it seems that dask tries to fit it in memory (and it doesn't fit).

Why does this happen? I expected that dask would do this iteratively. How can I write the target file in chunks?

Below is the code that I'm using.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.read_parquet(
    '/path/to/file/file.pq',
    engine='pyarrow'
)

ddf = ddf.rename(columns={'old_column_name': 'new_column_name'})

# the step which fails
ddf.to_parquet(
    '/path/to/file/edited/',
    engine='pyarrow',
    write_index=False
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What error do you get? It doesn't read the actual data until you do `to_parquet`. That's why it only fails at the last step if it's memory-related. Try changing the chunksize parameter of read_parquet. I wonder if there's a why to change the column name on disk without reading the whole thing though...

Comment: No, there is no convenient way to change the column name in-place. Using byte editing, you may be able to do it for a name of the same length as the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dask does indeed load your data in chunks, and writes them to the output in chunks. The total memory usage will depend on

- the size of each chunk, known as "row-groups" in parquet, which are not divisible. You need the in-memory size, after decompression and decoding
- the number of chunks you process at once, which may be the number of cores in your CPU if you don't configure otherwise

Note that *some* intermediate values are also needed during processing, so you generally want each thread of each worker to be able to fit a god deal more than just one chunk's worth of data.